# outer join for parent child chain

Tags: sql, outer-join

Considering below tables and relationships:

parent --1:Many-- children --1:Many-- subchildren

- Parent may or many not have children 
  records.
- children always have subchildren records.

I want to write a query to select parent names where any if matched
parent.name,children.name or subchildren.name.

Here I understand I have to do a left outer join between parent and children. But what kind of join should I put between children and subchildren ?

Comment: What is the actual database product in use or is that part of the join-fu trials? :)

Comment: You can INNER JOIN children and subchildren, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, this works:

```
declare @theName char(25)
select @theName = 'dave'

SELECT p.id, p.name 
FROM parent p
LEFT OUTER JOIN child c   -- OUTER in case there's no children
    ON p.id = c.parentid
INNER JOIN grandchild g   -- INNER because you say there's always children
    ON c.id = g.parentid
WHERE p.name = @theName
    OR c.name = @theName
    OR g.name = @thename
GROUP BY p.id, p.name     -- GROUP BY to combine multiple hits
```

**Edited (after being accepted) to add:** I would actually use `OUTER` for the second `JOIN` as well, just in case the rules change without warning. It won't hurt if it's not needed.

Answer (score 0):

If children always have subchildren you should use INNER JOIN

Answer (score 0):

This query will return all parent (with or withour children), and return nulls in the columns for those parents that do not have any children.

```
SELECT  *
FROM    Parent p LEFT JOIN
        Children c ON p.ID = c.ParentID LEFT JOIN
        SubChildren sc ON c.ID = sc.ChildID
```

If you were to change the JOIN between Children and SubChildren to INNER

```
SELECT  *
FROM    Parent p LEFT JOIN
        Children c ON p.ID = c.ParentID INNER JOIN
        SubChildren sc ON c.ID = sc.ChildID
```

*Then you will not get the rows from parents that do not hav any children.*

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  p.*
FROM    (
        SELECT  id
        FROM    parent
        WHERE   name = 'myname'
        UNION
        SELECT  parent_id
        FROM    child
        WHERE   name = 'myname'
        UNION
        SELECT  c.parent_id
        FROM    child c
        JOIN    grandchild gc
        ON      gc.parent_id = c.id
        WHERE   gc.name = 'myname'
        ) q
JOIN    parent p
ON      p.id = q.id
```

Comment: You can combine the 2nd and 3rd SELECTs into one.

Comment: He's says there are always grandchildren, so you can `INNER JOIN` child and grandchild.

Comment: @egrunin: yes I can. Now how do I separate children and grandchildren with a certain name?

Comment: His question is ambiguous. I read it to mean, "show me all people who have someone named 'dave' in their family tree". If that's correct, then you only need one parent even if there are multiple 'daves' among the descendants.